# How to write binary data into a string or stringstream?

Tags: c++, stringstream, stdstring

I want to write binary bytes (for example, 0xAA and 0xDD) into a stringstream.

```
const uint8_t sync_word_1 = 0xAA;
const uint8_t sync_word_2 = 0xDD;

std::stringstream ss;
ss.write((char*)&sync_word_1, sizeof(sync_word_1));
ss.write((char*)&sync_word_2, sizeof(sync_word_2));

// print for debug
for (int i = 0; i < ss.str().size(); i++) {
    printf("0x%02X ", ss.str()[i]);
}
```

What I expect:

```
0xAA 0xDD
```

What I got:

```
0xFFFFFFAA 0xFFFFFFDD
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Try with `1` instead of `sizeof(sync_word_1)`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, nothing changed, thanks anyway.

Comment: Your `printf` is wrong, you're printing an integer but passing a character

Comment: @Alan Yepp, agree: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd27e500b4fd34ea)

Comment: @Scheff, thank you!

Comment: _What did I miss?_ `printf()` is a function using variadic arguments for the added values. These values are always subject of promotion. Hence, `char` is passed as `int`. To tell `printf()` that it was originally a `char`, you have to use "formatting modifier" - i.e. `%hhx` instead of `%x`.

Comment: FYI: [Variadic arguments - Default conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Default_conversions)